# Exist-db Add node with XQUERY

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have a listPers.xml (TEI List containing persons, obviously ) . I want to write a function to update the listPers.xml
My function looks like this:

```
declare function app:addPerson($node as node(), $model as map(*)) {
    let $person := "<person xml:id=""><persName><forename>Albert</forename><surname>Test</surname></persName></person>"
    let $list := doc(concat($config:app-root, '/resources/listPers_test.xml'))
    return 
    update insert $person into $list//tei:listPerson
};
```

And the listPerson.xml
looks more or less like a typical list with person-entries
I have a tei:header (here omitted) followed by

```
  <text>
        <body>
            <listPerson xml:id="person">
                <person xml:id="abbadie_jacques">
                    <persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/100002307">
                        <forename>Jacques</forename>
                        <surname>Abbadie</surname>
                    </persName>
                    <note>Prediger der französisch-reformierten Gemeinde in <rs type="place" ref="#berlin">Berlin</rs>
                    </note>
                </person>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

(sorry for ruining indentions, it's just an excerpt )
I do not get an error, which means that my app:addPerson should be fine, right?
I want the listPers_test to look like this:

```
   <text>
        <body>
            <listPerson xml:id="person">
                <person xml:id="abbadie_jacques">
                    <persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/100002307">
                        <forename>Jacques</forename>
                        <surname>Abbadie</surname>
                    </persName>
                    <note>Prediger der französisch-reformierten Gemeinde in <rs type="place" ref="#berlin">Berlin</rs>
                    </note>
                </person>
    <!-- here comes the output that I wish to have :-) -->
    <person xml:id=""><persName><forename>Albert</forename><surname>Test</surname></persName></person>
    </body>
    </text>
    </TEI>
```

In the long run, I aim for an html-form that allows users to input names etc., where ids are generated using sth like

```
to-lowercase(concat($surname, "_", $forename));
```

But I will not get into my questions regarding forms and xquery, as I have barely done a quick Google-trip regarding html forms and xquery!

Can anyone hint me at why I do not get the listPers_test.xml file updated with the second value? :-)

All the best and thanks in advance to everyone,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have a solution for anyone interested in it:

My first snippet `$person:= ...` contains a STRING, not an element.Changing the line

```
 let $person := "<person xml:id=""><persName><forename>Albert</forename><surname>Test</surname></persName></person>"
```

to this one actually solves the issue:

```
 let $person := <tei:person xml:id=""><persName><forename>Albert</forename><surname>Test</surname></persName></tei:person>
```